# What is the best way to notify a user when a SQL Server database table cell is still empty after a certain period of time?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, entity-framework, asp.net-core

I am building an `ASP.NET Core` web app in C#. Clients can add an `"inquiry"` and the target response time is less than 30 minutes. Table "Inquiries" has many columns, among them: `Id`, `Inquiry`, and `Reply`.

Here is the scenario:

```
10h00: Client A adds an inquiry
10h09: No reply yet
10h10: Employee B gets notified that an inquiry has been added and has no reply yet
10h04: No reply yet
10h09: No reply yet
10h20: Employee B gets notified that an inquiry has been added and has no reply yet
10h21: Employee B adds reply and stops getting notified (B was getting notified every 10 minutes)
```

What would you say is the best approach to get this to work? I suppose I can write a C# function to check for empty "Reply" cells every 30 seconds, but I think it would exhaust memory when the database grows bigger, right? Can you point me in the right direction?

Comment: `SqlDependency` maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few options here for this.
Personally, I would schedule an event in a secondary service to trigger tasks at a time window, but that may be overkill in your case.

Within your Inquiries, you (you probably already have this field) can use a last modified or last updated field to determine when this row was altered last via a calculation.

If you don't have a requirement of Source Control for your DB script, you can use stored procedures to manage this data and control the creating of these date/time stamps.

I would recommend updating your query to have a where clause on both the Last Updated time AND the null condition. This way there is no unnecessary records being processed and checked.

POST EDIT Alteration:
It seems like you have a creation date of events within the database, compare them to the current time on your retrieval query for determining an alert status.

About memory/performance impact:

The (C# application) memory impact will be based on the number of items returned, and not the number of items in the Database. So, if you add a where clause onto your query, you'll be able to ensure that the memory isn't allocated to misc. objects.